# CSS animation moving unwanted objects

Tags: html, css, animation

I am using a hover animation on an image, when hovering the image grows.
However this also moves the text underneath, and I do not want that.

How do I make it so it ignores the text?

```css
aside div {
  background: url('http://www.law.kuleuven.be/canon_law/Pictures/staff/pasfoto.jpg/download');
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}

aside div:hover {
  padding: 0;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

aside section {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>
    <section>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>placeholder <br /> more placeholder.</p>
    </section>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: @Naren's answer with `position: absolute` works. But, alternatively, you could use [`transform: scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) instead of changing the `width` and `height` of the div, and it should work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```css
aside div {
  background: url('http://www.law.kuleuven.be/canon_law/Pictures/staff/pasfoto.jpg/download');
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
aside> section{
position:relative;
}
aside> section> div{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
right:0px;
margin:auto;
top:0px;
}
aside >section> div:hover {
  padding: 0;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

aside > section {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
}
section > h1{
  padding-top:125px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>
    <section>
      <div>
      </div>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>placeholder <br /> more placeholder.</p>
    </section>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: You're a hero !

Comment: @Icarus Thank you :)